# How to configure standalone confluent rest proxy

Tags: docker-compose, confluent-rest-proxy

I am running the standalone confluent kafka rest proxy from a docker image as described [here](https://developer.confluent.io/get-started/rest/#start-rest-proxy).  I also see the configuration options described [here](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/kafka-rest/production-deployment/rest-proxy/config.html#kafkarest-config)

My question is:  how, or where, do I set the configuration options so that the proxy running in the docker container sees them?

I read the documentation but don't see how to add configuration options to the docker image.

I am using this docker compose yml:

```
---
version: '2'
services:

  rest-proxy:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka-rest:7.5.0
    ports:
      - 8082:8082
    hostname: rest-proxy
    container_name: rest-proxy
    environment:
      KAFKA_REST_HOST_NAME: rest-proxy
      KAFKA_REST_LISTENERS: "http://0.0.0.0:8082"
      KAFKA_REST_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: $BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS
      KAFKA_REST_SECURITY_PROTOCOL: "$SECURITY_PROTOCOL"
      KAFKA_REST_SASL_JAAS_CONFIG: $SASL_JAAS_CONFIG
      KAFKA_REST_SASL_MECHANISM: $SASL_MECHANISM
      KAFKA_REST_CLIENT_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: $BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS
      KAFKA_REST_CLIENT_SECURITY_PROTOCOL: "SASL_SSL"
      KAFKA_REST_CLIENT_SASL_JAAS_CONFIG: $SASL_JAAS_CONFIG
      KAFKA_REST_CLIENT_SASL_MECHANISM: $SASL_MECHANISM
```

Comment: Use volume or copy config files into the container with a Dockerfile, build a custom image.

Comment: Can you edit your question with your compose file?

Comment: Where should the config files end up?

Comment: Try these: /etc/kafkaui/dynamic_config.yaml | /bitnami or use environment variables: https://medium.com/@tetianaokhotnik/docker-compose-for-kafka-single-broker-in-kraft-mode-kafka-ui-and-confluent-rest-proxy-7334da721d4c